# UnicodeEncode Error while running a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I wrote the following python script for retrieving the information from Yahoo Finance website and store it in a file. Following is the script:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
in_data = open('list_of_companies.txt','r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
for line in in_data:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s='+line.strip())
    page = page.read()
    page = page.decode('utf-8','ignore')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    ans = line[0:len(line.strip())]
    ans += '.txt'
    f1 = open(ans,'w')
    f1.write(soup.prettify())
    f1.close()
```

It will take input symbol from `list_of_companies.txt` and store it in a file with that name. However, when i am running this script, this is giving me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Darshil Babel\Desktop\NewsContent\s.py", line 12, in <module>
    f1.write(soup.prettify())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03cb' in position 1556: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using **urllib** and **BeautifulSoup** module for this purpose.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened your output file without specifying a Unicode-compatible encoding. Try

```
f1 = open(ans,'w', encoding='utf-8')
```